# How to set request body and params on $resource POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm attempting to pass data in the request body and a request parameter to an Angular $resource call. Below is my click handler from my controller and the service which it calls:

controller.js:

```
vm.setLimit = function(limit) {
  var data = {
    activity: 'point_limit',
    limit: limit
  };
  playersService.setPlayerLimit({
    playerId: playerId,
    data
  });
};
```

service.js:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .factory('playersService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/players/:playerId/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getPlayerInfo: {method: 'GET', url: base + 'playerInfo'},
        setPlayerLimit: {method: 'POST', url: base + 'playerLimit'}
      });
    }]);
```

`getPlayerInfo` works, but `setPlayerLimit` does not because, for some reason, it is not being passed the `playerId`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`playersService.setPlayerLimit` should take 4 parameters in order:

**(request parameters, request body, success callback, error callback)**

Modify your code as:

```
playersService.setPlayerLimit({playerId: playerId}, data, success, error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3852)

'Use the overloaded `method(params, payload)` signature' as below:

```
vm.setPlayerLimit = function(limit) {
  playersService.setPlayerLimit({playerId: playerId}, {activity: 'point_limit', limit: limit});
};
```